# Prove $\alpha$ is the greatest element in $[a,b]$ with $f(\alpha)=0$

Tags: calculus, elementary-set-theory, continuity

This question comes in one of the Spivak's exercises about continuous function on $[a,b]$ with $f(a)<0<f(b)$

> Consider the set $B=[x:a\le x \le b$ and $f(x)<0]$

Since $a\in B$ and for $\forall x \in B,\space b \ge x$, the set is non-empty and bounded above, hence least upper bound $\alpha$ exists.

Because $f$ is continuous, there $\exists\delta_1,\delta_2>0$ with $f(x)<0$ whenever $\alpha - \delta_1<x<\alpha + \delta_1$ and $f(x)>0$ whenever $\alpha - \delta_2<x<\alpha + \delta_2$.

Therefore $a<\alpha<b$

If $f(\alpha)<0$ or $f(\alpha)>0$, we can lead to contradiction that $\alpha$ is not least upper bound of the set B, hence it follows that $f(\alpha)=0$

The claim I want to prove is that $\alpha $ is the greatest element of the set $S=[x:a\le x\le b$ and $f(x)=0]$.

Somewhat related are the sets:

> $A=[x:a\le x\le b$ and $f$ is negative on $[a,x]]$

and

> $C = [x:a\le x\le b$ and $f(x) \le 0]$.

For these last two sets, one can prove that $\alpha$ is the least element in $[a,b]$ and greatest element in $[a,b]$ with $f(\alpha)=0$ respectively.

However I do not know how one can show it is the case with the set $B$.

In short, I want to prove that if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $f(a)<0<f(b)$ then the least upper bound $\alpha$ of the set $B=[x:a\le x \le b$ and $f(x)<0]$ is the greatest element in $[a,b]$ with $f(\alpha)=0$.

Comment: What you want to prove is false. Just consider a function with several zeros in $[a,b]$.

Comment: I think one easy example is $x^2(x+1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually $\alpha$ may not be the greatest element in $S$ since $f$ can have some local minimum at some point $\beta>\alpha$ with $f(\beta)=0$.

For example, consider the function $f(x)=x(x-{1 \over 2})^2$ on the interval $[-1,1]$. The least upper bound of $B$ is $0$, but there is some $\beta={1 \over 2}>0$ with $f({1 \over 2})=0$.